# How can I avoid duplicate code in data structures?

Tags: c, data-structures, code-duplication

In my c project I have 2 structs, and I need a basic dynamic array for each of them containing the same functions. How can I avoid duplicate code, since c doesn't have templates or generics?

Comment: It's not clear what you're describing. But if you have working code and you're trying to clean up the programming style, [codereview.se] would be the place to ask.

Comment: You could have both structs A and B contain a third struct C that contains the common stuff...

Comment: You can help us help you by posting your structures. Or at least posting something that represents your structures. Show us what you described.